# Unable to connect to Docker daemon WINDOWS

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, command-line-interface, daemon

I've installed Stable Docker Desktop for WINDOWS 10. I tried running:

```
docker run hello-world
    Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.
```

So it appears that it can connect to Docker daemon. However when I run my own command:

```
C:\Users\cortex>bash
DESKTOP-2GHN95P:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/cortex/# cortex deploy
```

I get following error:

```
error: unable to connect to the Docker daemon

please confirm Docker is running, or if Docker is not installed, install it by following the instructions for your operating system: https://docs.docker.com/install
```

I'm new to Docker and I can't figure out this problem. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run cortex from a WSL, which is trying to take action on the docker engine in the host OS. If you have WSL 2, you can enable the WSL 2 integration for Docker desktop in the settings. If that's not an option, you can always install docker on your WSL instead,